# Unable to access the cmd prompt in remote machine using openchannel in java

Tags: java, jsch

```
I'm trying to access the cmd prompt in administrator mode and run a batch file in the remote machine,but right now I'm not able to access the cmd prompt through openchannel. Did anybody tried to access it from remote machine in java?
```

Here is the code

```
java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
JSch jsch = new JSch();
session = jsch.getSession(user, ip, 22);
session.setPassword(password);
session.setTimeout(timeOut);
session.setConfig(config);
session.connect();
System.out.println("session connected");
//open command prompt to run the command = "C:\\executeBatchFile.bat" file
Channel channel = (ChannelExec) session.openChannel("exec");
((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand("cmd.exe /c \"echo %cd%\"\\executeBatchFile.bat");
channel.connect();
InputStream outputstream_from_the_channel = channel.getInputStream();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(outputstream_from_the_channel));
String jarOutput;
 while ((jarOutput = reader.readLine()) != null)
 {
  System.out.println("Inside while loop");
  System.out.println(jarOutput + "\n");
 }
reader.close();
session.disconnect();
```

Expected behavior :set command should run as an administrator(though I have logged in as admin),come back to the c:drive (cd) and execute the batch file ie; C:executeBatchFile.bat

Actual behaviour : command gives the user path(not as admin) when I print the jarOutput. ie; C:\Users\Admin\executeBatchFile.bat

could you suggest any solution on the same?

Comment: Did you try FTP API ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the relevant code from your program and describe what happens when you run it. Include any error messages or exceptions that you get, including stacktraces. Ideally, you should post a small self-contained program which demonstrates the problem that you're having.

Comment: @Kenster - Could you help me on this?

Comment: The issue is with Windows when you run cmd.exe it does not inherit the admin rights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
This has been resolved using PsExec command instead of JSCH

String pscommand=E:\\Tool\\psexec -u user -p pwd \\\\ip -s -d cmd.exe /c C:\\executescript.bat

 process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(pscommand);

      InputStream es = process.getErrorStream();

      BufferedReader errReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(es));
      String line;

      // Read STDOUT into a buffer.
      while ((line = errReader.readLine()) != null)
      {
        system.out.println(line);
      }
```

**Could any one tell me how to open the cmd prompt in administrator mode(I logged in using admin credentials only but still it does not open in admin mode).Here I need to run the script in administrator.**